# Validating text value in protractor

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am new to protractor and I am try to validate the value in the text field. Below is my code

```
expect(element(by.model('myModelName')).getAttribute('value').toEqual('name'));
```

I am getting the below error

```
Message:
 TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'toEqual'
 Stacktrace:
 TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'toEqual'
 at null.<anonymous> (C:\IntegrationTesting\script\Spec.js:53:100)
```

I have done other validations based on by.bind with toEqual which, but this is the 1st time i am using this. I am not sure if my usage is correct. How can I get this working? Please help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the toEqual() after the expect:

```
expect(element(by.model('myModelName')).getAttribute('value')).toEqual('name');
```

The format should be:

```
expect(locator.getSomething()).toEqual('expected value');
```

Comment: Such a silly mistake. Thanks alot. It saved me lots of time. Hope I wont repeat this mistake.

Comment: I have another problem, hope dont mind answering it here. I am trying to make a selection like below        element.all(by.model('myModel')).get(5).click(), but it says Error: Index out of bound.only has 1 elements though it has 20 values. Is this the correct way of calling it?

Comment: it's correct, be sure that you have 6 (5+1) elements on the page

Comment: It has 20+ values as options, still throws the error message   Error: Index out of bound.only has 1 elements This is the actual definition of the element          <select ng-change="changeD()" class="xxx" ng-options="obj for obj in objs track by obj" name="yr" ng-model="myModel" required>       </select>

Answer (score 0):

wrong brackets:

```
expect(element(by.model('myModelName')).getAttribute('value')).toEqual('name');
```